# adding user on rabbitmq in debian shows /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: dirname: not found

Tags: rabbitmq, debian

i have tried sudo rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin123
got this response

```
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: 1: /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: dirname: not found
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: 20: .: Can't open /rabbitmq-env
```

Comment: What version of Debian, RabbitMQ, and Erlang? `dirname` is a standard command, usually located at `/usr/bin/dirname`. Can you check for it?

Comment: thanks for reply, its actually sorted out myself